# How to plot only boundary lines in gnuplot for data of the type (x,y,z)?

Tags: gnuplot, boundary

I have a data of the form x:y:z and currently I am plotting this data using Gnuplot with pm3d map. In this file, z values are either 0 or 1 or 2. Now I want to plot similar data from another file and this file in the same graph. Only thing is that from this file, I want to plot only the boundary of the region z=0 and nothing else. But the data from other file should look like a normal pm3d map. Is it possible to do this?

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand how your plot should look like. Do you have an example? You could also draw with a graphics program over you current result to show it. What do you mean by 'boundary'? Some kind of contour plot?

Comment: I have 2 data files. Both files have data of the type (x,y,z). In the first file, z is either 0,1,2. In the second file z is 0,2. If I plot first file using pm3d map in gnuplot, then I see a closed region in xy plane i.e. region in which z=0. Now in the second file, if we could plot only those x-y values on top of this pm3d plot for which z=0 (from 2nd file) then that would mark the boundary of the region which we already see. I want to show that boundary because that boundary I have obtained analytically while the data in first file is experimental.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to use the contour plot of the second file and the pm3d for the first.
be careful you may need to tune gnuplot, somthing like:

```
set contour  
set cntrparam lev disc 0.01 # just to be sure  
set pm3d map  
unset surface  
splot 'file1' w pm3d, 'file2' w l
```

if you want to remove points on one file based on the values of a second file you need to filter outside unless the two files have the same shape and you can join them together using the unix join or paste command and then filter